# Writing to a Wiki

Tags: perl, shell, wikipedia-api

I need to write a script that writes (appends) data to an internal wiki that isn't public (needs username and password but unencrypted, http not https). The script can be a shell script, a Perl script, or even a Java application (last resort). Any help would be appreciated. Let me know if any additional information is needed.

Right now, I'm only able to read from the wiki using LWP Perl library using the getprint($url) function.

Thanks

Comment: Use LWP to make appropriate HTTP requests to add the content. We can't tell you what those are because we do not know your software.

Comment: I guess my question is really is there a simpler way than intercepting what my browser sends and mimicking it in a script?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If it's truly MediaWiki, then just use [MediaWiki::API](http://search.cpan.org/~exobuzz/MediaWiki-API-0.35/lib/MediaWiki/API.pm).